# Please can someone give me the correct code to use to loop through this api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve information from a weather api so that I can get the info and show it like a 7 day weather report:

### day : 1

cloudcover : 1

wind, speed: 2

### day : 2

cloudcover : 3

wind, speed:6

etc.  So far I have this and it is not working and I don't know what code to use to even just get the value for cloudcover.

```
weatherApi( "http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=31.049999&lat=-29.883333&product=astro&output=json&unit=metric");
    
async function weatherApi(file) {
        let x = await fetch(file);
        let y = await x.text();
        
        const parsedJson = JSON.parse(y);
    
        
        
        let text = "";
        for (let i in parsedJson.dataseries.cloudcover) {
            text += parsedJson.dataseries.cloudcover[i] + ", ";
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Some code to get you started**

The weather API returns json data as shown in the sample below. "dataseries" is an array of weather metrics for each day.  So you can use the [fetch method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to retrieve the data and automatically convert json to an object. And once you have the object, you can [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) through the dataseries array to display each day. One way to display the data is by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which you can then append to the page.

```
{
    "product": "astro",
    "init": "2022060912",
    "dataseries": [{
        "timepoint": 3,
        "cloudcover": 1,
        "seeing": 6,
        "transparency": 3,
        "lifted_index": 2,
        "rh2m": 9,
        "wind10m": {
            "direction": "S",
            "speed": 4
        },
        "temp2m": 22,
        "prec_type": "none"
    }, 
    ...
```

**Demo Snippet**

Read the linked references and run the code snippet to better understand how it works.

```js
function getWeather(longitude, latitude, title) {

  const url = `https://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=${longitude}&lat=${latitude}&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0`;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

      let html = `<h3>Weather for ${title}</h3>`;

      data.dataseries.forEach((item, index) => {
        html += (`
        <div class="day">
          <strong>Day ${1 + index}</strong>
          <div>Cloud Cover: ${item.cloudcover}</div>
          <div>Wind Direction: ${item.wind10m.direction}</div>
          <div>Wind Speed: ${item.wind10m.speed}</div>
          <div>Temp: ${item.temp2m}</div>
        </div>
      `);
      });

      weather.innerHTML = html;

    });
}

  // lat -29.9 lat, long 31, Durban, South Africa

getWeather(31, -29.9, "Durban, South Africa");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.day {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="weather"></div>
```

**Update**

In a comment, OP asks how to build the display without using template literals:

```
    html += "<div class='day'>" +
    "<strong>Day " + (1 + index) + "</strong>" +
    "<div>Cloud Cover: " + item.cloudcover + "</div>" +
    "<div>Wind Direction: " + item.wind10m.direction + "</div>" +
    "<div>Wind Speed: " + item.wind10m.speed + "</div>" +
    "<div>Temp: " + item.temp2m + "</div>" +
    "</div>";
```

Comment: I striggled to figure out backticks, but essentially figured them out with an online tutorial. It makes my code grey out half way, even though it actually works. I really appreciate your response! Thank you for posting something that I can actually work through and study and figure out what I was doing wrong. 
I understand what you have said above about the JSOn and objects etc, what I can't understand is the foreach statement. Is it calling the 'dataseries' array only and then from there I can iterate through and get the cloudcover response etc? Is that correct in saying that?

Comment: @Wendy - I've added an update to the answer that shows how to build the display without using template literals.  And yes, you are correct about 'dataseries'.  It is a property of the data sent by the API and we can reference it using dot notation data.dataseries.  The forEach method allows us to loop through each element, but you could do the same thing with a standard for loop like data.dataseries[index].cloudcover.